# Label with a close Button JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to create a Label(Non-editable text field) with a close button?

On button click, the label should disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a button and trigger which label to make invisible:

```
Button moveBut = new Button("Hide Label"); 
moveBut.setOnAction(new EventHandler<actionevent>() {

 @Override 
 public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {  

     labelName.setVisible(false);

                                      } 

   });
```

Here is a [Link](http://java.about.com/od/Javafx-Layouts/ss/Borderpane-Example-Program.htm) which shows how to hide/un-hide `Labels` from different region using `BorderPane` layout.

Answer (score 3):

Joey's answer works, but note that you can embed the button inside the label by using it as the label's graphic:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LabelWithCloseButton extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button closeButton = new Button("X");

        // In real life, use an external style sheet rather than inline styles: 
        // I did it this way for brevity 
        closeButton.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 6pt; -fx-text-fill:red;");

        Label label = new Label("Click the button to close");
        label.setGraphic(closeButton);
        label.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

        HBox root = new HBox(label);
        closeButton.setOnAction(event -> root.getChildren().remove(label));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```